# Restarting 1 Application server(java process) on GCP VM is resulting in bad performance across all Application VMs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, restart

I have 3 java applications servers running on GCP VMs.  I am getting 2000 TPS.

The URL is a simple GET call to display the log level using actuator end point. I brought down one of the application servers and the load was distributed across other VMs with good TPS.   However, the minute I brought up the VM which was shutdown, the performance on all 3 VMs have degraded and my TPS drops to 1000.

Has anyone seen this issue on GCP VMs before?  Any information on how to debug further on this?

Comment: How you are distributing the load? load balancer? are you using managed instance group?

Comment: We have nginx as the load balancer. Just to eliminate nginx as the bottleneck i have tried hitting the application ip directly from the jmeter. Still no luck. No we not using managed instance groups.